# What is the time function of this loop

Tags: time-complexity

```
For (i=0, i < n, i++) // n+1
{
    for(j=0; j < n, j++) // n * (n+1)
    {
       C[i][j]+ B[i,j]; // n * n
    }
}
```

The instructor said the time function is f(n) = 2n^2 +2n +1
How come it's not 2n^2+ 2n + 2 because both loops run one extra time when i=n and j=n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time we increment i, we check if the new value becomes equal to or greater than n, so we perform the comparison n + 1 times (n times when i <n and an additional comparison when i becomes equal to n). the same thing for j => (n+1) * (n times when i<n).

So, n*n+(n+1)*n+(n+1)=2n^2+ 2n +1